# Handling data response from $resource in angular js

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

I have a `RESTful` application with `Laravel 4` and `Angular JS`.

In my Laravel Controller,

```
public function index() {

  $careers = Career::paginate( $limit = 10 );

  return Response::json(array(
    'status'  => 'success',
    'message' => 'Careers successfully loaded!',
    'careers' => $careers->toArray()),
    200
  );
}
```

And the angular script,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('Data', function(){
    return {
        root_path: "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/"
    };
});

app.factory( 'Career', [ '$resource', 'Data', function( $resource, Data ) {
   return $resource( Data.root_path + 'api/v1/careers/:id', { id: '@id'});
}]);

function CareerCtrl($scope, $http, Data, Career) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.careers = Career.query(); 
    };
}
```

Here I am little confused to handle the response data to assign to scope variable, now I am getting empty array `[]` in `$scope.careers`. And also How can I handle success and error to show some messages like the following normal `$http service`,

```
$scope.init = function () {

    Data.showLoading(); // loading progress
    $http({method: 'GET', url: Data.root_path + 'api/v1/careers'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        Data.hideLoading();
        $scope.careers = data.careers.data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        if(data.error.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
            errorNotification(data.error.message); 
        } else {
            errorNotification();
        }

        $scope.careers = [];
    });
};
```

See my request in console using $resource.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.factory( 'Career', [ '$resource', 'Data', function( $resource, Data ) {
   return $resource( Data.root_path + 'api/v1/careers/:id', { id: '@id'}, {
    query: {
        isArray: false,
        method: 'GET'
    }
   });
}]);


Career.query(function(res) {
   $scope.careers = res.careers.data;
}, function(error) {
  // Error handler code
});
```

Comment: same here been struggling for hours

Answer (score 2):

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

```
$scope.init = function () {
    var success = function(careerList, getResponseHeaders){
      $scope.careers = careerList;
    };
    var failure = function(data){
      // TODO
    };
    Career.query(success, failure); 
};
```

Due to this quirks and other annoyances I would suggest to use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) instead of the default $resource . It makes life much easier

Comment: My first question, Why I am getting empty array [] in $scope.careers ?

Comment: It's not failure.see the screen-shot, I am getting all values, how can I map this to scope variable?

Comment: do you get that screenshot with the $resource call or with the $http call ?  Also try the new code edited. You get the data on the callback and that might be ran after the query function returns.

Comment: The screen-shot is from $resource, and using your code also I am getting same and ``$scope.careers`` as ``undefined``